# Authorize.net Changing Credit Card info

Tags: wordpress, permissions, authorize.net

I've got Wordpress Subscriber level users set to see their Dashboard and can get to their Contributions, and even to the Change Billing Details section.  However, upon saving changes to the credit card, the user is getting a "You do not have permission to cancel Subscription" error message.  Any clue as to what permission I am missing?  Is it the CiviCRM: access contact reference fields or CiviCRM: access AJAX API or something entirely different?

We are using recurring payments on Authorize.net, utilizing the tokens.  Wordpress 4.4.2. and CiviCRM 4.7.2 on a PHP 5.4 CentOS 6 install.